# Rails controllers and instance variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A typical rails controller might do something like this:

```
class FoosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @foos = Foo.all
  end
end
```

I understand rails well enough to know that `@foos` will return an array of Foo objects, but that `@foos` itself is an instance variable.

So which object does the instance variable belong to? Would it be an instance of the FoosController class? Is a different instance of this object created every time I access the index page? What about if I access the show page, where a new variable `@foo` is introduced:

```
def show
  @foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
end
```

Does this variable belong to the same object that @foos belongs to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Correct; it belongs to the instance of `FoosController` that's processing the current request.
2. Yes, each request creates a new instance of the controller–that's why instance variables can be used to hold state for a single request.
3. Yes, but: if `index` isn't called, `@foos` won't be initialized, There is no `@foos` instance variable when the `show` action is hit in the code you show<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> *If you called `index` from `show`, then `@foos` would be initialized and available on the page. Not that you should do this, because that's confusing concerns.*

Comment: Good explanation. To add, `@foos` is an array containing instances of the `Foo` objects.

Comment: @Anil Thanks. I think the OP mentioned what `@foos` contains, so I didn't add it :)

Comment: I know you don't miss anything. But I like it when I can get all my knowledge in one spot. This is the type of question which helps the OP a little now, but has a long term value to the communtiy.